# AES-CTR mode (streaming-like encryption) a 1 bit change in plaintext changes 1 bit in ciphertext?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, block-cipher, stream-cipher

From what I understand, in stream-cipher (or AES CTR mode) the key is actually being encrypted using the IV (or in general, from key K we produce pseudo-random bytes). Than, we use this key to encrypt the plaintext using XOR.

But from what I understand, assuming that the same key K is being used, a change of one bit in the plaintext changes only 1 bit the ciphertext.

Am I right, or did I get it totally wrong?

And if I am right, isn't it less secure than CBC? (Because in CBC a change of one bit in the plaintext, changes all the bits in ciphertext from the point of the change an on)

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the CTR mode violates [Shannon's diffusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion), since changing a bit in the plaintext only changes a bit in the output. However this is only part of the story. In fact, you also have to change the IV for each message. Therefore many bits will change in the following message even if you change only a single bit in the plaintext or even if the message remains the same.

On the other hand, if you are concerned with malicous modification of messages, neither CTR nor CBC are safe against those attacks and, as @GregS said, you should use authenticated encryption modes such as CCM, GCM, or [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode).

Comment: CTR mode just implements a stream cipher using a block cipher.

Comment: @GregS No, that's OFB (Output Feedback) mode.

Comment: Or rather, yes, CTR mode allows you to use a block cipher like a stream cipher, but that's not all it does, since it also allows random access.

Comment: Also CFB is a stream cipher mode (a self-synchronizing one). OFB, CFB and CTR are the 3 most popular ways of running a stream cipher using a block cipher. They have different trade-offs. CTR seems to be the most popular nowadays, among other things due to the random access property.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, that is why there are modes that incorporate both CTR mode and data authentication, commonly referred to as [AEAD](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/AEAD_block_cipher_modes_of_operation) modes, for example [CCM](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/CCM_mode) and [GCM](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/GCM_mode) modes.

Answer (score 3):

This is *exactly* why you must **never** repeat a portion of the keystream when using CTR mode, just as with a stream cipher.  The counter used on the encrypting side must only ever go forward, until the key is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Except not key is being encrypted, but IV (counter) is encrypted using the key.
This approach allows random access to encrypted stream (since counter is known for each portion of data).